# JavaFX window takes a while to load and getting an error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, timeout

When I try to run the default JavaFX code in Eclipse, it takes a while for the window to open and I get this error:

com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6
WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation

It works fine on my Windows PC, I only get this error on my Mac.

The window didn't open at all until I unchecked the -XstartOnFirstThread argument in Run Configurations. But I'm still getting the error.

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,100,100);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify that you have installed the correct Java/FX for your Mac's processor, ARM64 vs. x64, and try running from the command line.

Comment: Also ensure that you are using the most recent JDK andJavaFX versions (21).

Comment: Turns out I had the x64 installed on my M1 Mac. So I uninstalled everything Eclipse, OpenJDK, JavaFX and downloaded the correct versions, but I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bug in MacOS 14, and will be fixed in version 22.
[Application window not activated in macOS 14 Sonoma](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8315657)

Comment: It looks like the problem has been fixed and backported. Here are the versions in which it has been fixed: ***jfx21.0.2***, ***jfx21.0.1***, ***jfx17.0.9***, ***8u401***.

Answer (score 2):

Try to downgrade to macOS Ventura. My older projects with javaFX are not working after macOS Sonoma 14.0 update while getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is opening in background. So it works, but you just need to look for the new created window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error in Sonoma version 14.0. However, I did not see any impact on the operability of the application. The Java GUI is running and just creates a window in the background.

Various sources suggest that after doing File -> Invalidate Caches, you should delete the .idea file and reopen the project.

I did not try this solution because it did not prevent the application from running. However, developers whose application does not work at all can try this solution in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).